# ASP.Net, How to ignore the MasterPage does not exist error?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, virtualpathprovider

I am working on my CMS project based on ASP.Net MVC2, I have implemented my **VirtualPathProvider** and **VirtualFile** for my master page, to use a master page in db.

It works as below: 
I indicate the MasterPageFile in the aspx/ascx file.

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="/Content.master"
```

Then override **VirtualPathProvider.GetFile** to load the master page from db, "/Content.master" is the key to search in the db.

Everything works fine for me, except

IF I click "Build Web Site" in the context menu in VS2010, I will get an error says "The file '/Content.master' does not exist."

My master page is stored in db and this error is normal, **Is there a way that VS2010 can ignore this error?**

I am looking into the BuildManager relative code, seems complicated.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another way to avoid using MasterPageFile property

Add a custom property PageTemplate in System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage/ViewMasterPage derived classes

Comment: Could you provide some more details? This doesn't seem to do the trick for me : I get an error: Type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage' does not have a public property named 'embeddedmasterpagefile'